# Win32 : Create tab control from a DLG file. How is it possible?

Tags: c, winapi

Good morning,

In our company, we use again WIN32 with dialog box who has been created in DLG file extension.

Let me tell you.

In DLG file, we define set of dialog box and windows who is gonna be used in our application.

And in the code C or C++, to call one or another DialogBox, we use the standard function DialogBox or again DialogBoxParam. For every dialog box, we use a file as controller who contains a WinMain with events loop in order to manage button clicks, hidding components, and so on.

There is a dialog box wherein I would like to use tab control. Is it possible to put every tab control with its components in my '*.DLG' file and to call it in my code C++ in order to be used not as window but tab control ?. If yes, how ? Otherwise, I stay opened to each other possibilities.

Thank you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/property-sheet-reference

Comment: You are attributing features to a [tab control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tab-controls) which it doesn't have. A tab control is literally just the individual tabs and a display area. You are free to host any window or dialog inside the display area. So yes, it is perfectly possible to load multiple dialogs that are implemented in isolation.

Comment: However it is not possible to do that with just the dialog resource. You have to create those non-modal dialogs yourself from additional dialog resources.

Comment: Are you trying to create template for [tab control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tab-controls#creating-tab-controls) like there is [template for Dialog box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dialogboxa)?